# nutch regex, how to implement crawling strategy

Tags: regex, nutch

I try to establish the follwoing crawling behaviour in a nutch 1.8 in environment in the regex-urlfilter.txt file:

First:
Crawl Startpage (www.domainname.com) of the Site defined in the seed.txt file.
Second:
Additionally only crawl pages of two specific directories "directoryname1" (www.domainname.com/directoryname1/...) and "directoryname2" (www.domainname.com/directoryname2/...) linked from the start page and disregard everything else.

So far the filters I tried were either too general and the crawler crawled the start page and all other directories (not only directory 1 and 2), or were too strict, so that the crawler did not start at all (as the seed-URL did not match the regex of the urlfilter for the directory).

Thanks for your help chris

Answer (score 1):

I solved it on my own. Here my solution to it: 
regex for just the start page 
+^.*[.]de/$ 
regex for directory 1 
+.*/directoryname1/.* 
regex for directory 2 
+.*/directoryname2/.*